# Importing in Rust

Tags: rust, import, module

I'm a newbie in Rust.

I have this file structure now:

```
└── src
    ├── another.rs
    └── some_file.rs
```

In the `some_file` file, I have this code:

```
mod another;

// and code
```

However, the compiler throws an error and offers this help:

```
 = help: to create the module `another`, create file "src/some_file/another.rs" or "src/some_file/another/mod.rs"
```

But I don't want to do so. I want both files to be in the same directory. Are there any ways I can avoid creating a new directory?

Comment: only some file can declare mod using file, there is a layout you need to follow

Comment: do you have a `main.rs` or `lib.rs` file?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to do so? By declaring `mod another` within `some_file.rs`, you're declaring it to be a submodule of the latter—so placing it within a subfolder means that the file structure is consistent with the logical module structure.  If you want a different logical module structure, then you should declare the module in a different place (possibly then bringing it into scope as required, eg with a `use` statement). If you *really* want a different file structure to logical module structure (generally A Bad Idea), you can use a `#[path = "..."]` attribute on the `mod` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a *binary* project, you need to have `src/main.rs`. In your `main.rs` if you put `mod another`, Rust will be looking for `src/another.rs` and it will work as expected.

If you have this structure:

```
└── src
    ├── another.rs
    ├── main.rs
    └── some_file.rs
```

and want to use `another` in `some_file`, then you shouldn't use `mod` in `some_file`, but only import it via `use crate::another;`.